# Valueerror when filtering and adding a new column at once

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering, valueerror, columnsorting

I'm getting the error code:
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1.

What i want to do is import a dataset and count the duplicated values, drop the duplicated values and add a column which says that there were x number of duplicates of that number.

This is to try and sort a dataset of 13 000 rows and 45 columns.
I've tried different solutions found online but it seems like it does not help. I'm pretty new to programming and all help is really appreciated

```
'''import pandas as pd
# Making file ready
data = pd.read_excel(r'Some file.xlsx', header = 0)

data.rename(columns={'Dato': 'Last ordered', 'ArtNr': 'Item No:'}, inplace 
= True)

#Formatting dates
pd.to_datetime(data['Last ordered'],
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Creates new table content and order
df = data[['Item No:','Last ordered', 'Description']]

df['Last ordered'] = df['Last ordered'].dt.strftime('%Y-/%m-/%d')
df = df.sort_values('Last ordered', ascending = False)

#Adds total sold quantity column
df['Quantity'] = df.groupby('Item No:').transform('count')

df2 = df.drop_duplicates('Item No:').reset_index(drop=True)

#Prints to environment and creates new excel file
print(df2)
df2.to_excel(r'New Sorted File.xlsx')'''
```

I expect it to provide a new excel file with columns:
Item No | Last ordered | Description | Quantity
And i want to be able to add other columns from the original dataset as well if i need to later on.

Comment: The problem is at this line: df['Quantity'] = df.groupby('Item No:').transform('count').  The right side part of the assignment is a dataframe and you are trying to fit it inside  a column. What do you want the 'Quantity' column to look like?

Comment: @micric        Thanks, this made sense.. I want to count the duplicated Item no. and add a row which says how many duplicates there is. This would be equal to a list of many sold items where i want to sort them by date and skip the duplicates, so the only remaining item no: are those who where last sold with their respective dates. However, i need to know how many times they are sold in total, which is equal to the 'quantity' column i'm trying to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

```
df['Quantity'] = df.groupby('Item No:').transform('count')
```

The right side part of the assignment is a dataframe and you are trying to fit it inside a column. You need to select only one of the columns. Something like

```
df['Quantity'] = df.groupby('Item No:').transform('count')['Description']
```

should work.

Comment: This seems to work. However, why is it so? what happens when you add ['Description']? can it just as well be ['Some other column']?

Comment: Yes, it can be any column. The dataframe you create with groupby and transform creates all identical columns.

Comment: i get an warning for doing it this way. as i understand the code wil create a copy ofthe dataset?..

Comment: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['Quantity'] = df.groupby('Item No:').transform('count')['Description'] #Adds total sold quantity column

Comment: I think it depends on the Pandas version, I  don't receive that warning. Pandas is warning you that you are using a chained assignment (.df.groupby.transform['']) and you might do it wrong. You can ignore it.